# Link to php form with fixed value?

Tags: php, forms

I made a registration form for competitions we are organising.
In this form you have to choose competition from index window to sign in.

Is there any possibility to make some link (using `<a href>`) in html to be redirected to registration form with an already chosen competition (some fixed value)?

Comment: Could you please share us how the form is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GET parameter.

```
<a href='www.example.com/?CompName=competitionName'>Competition Name</a>

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['CompName'])){
        $sCompetitionName = $_GET['CompName'];
    }
?>
```

Then when your creating the list of options check to see if the name matches that of the list name. If it does select it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use a $_GET param to do that. First on your competitions list page add a link to your form page.

```
<a href="url-to-competition-page?competition=your-value-here">Register for YOUR COMPETITION NAME HERE</a>
```

Then on your competitions registration form look for the get param. In the example below I will use a html select box.

```
$competitions = [
    'competition-value' => 'Competition name',
    'competition-value-2' => 'Competition name 2',
];

// Look for your get param, if it is not found set a default. In this case an empty string
$selectedCompetition = (isset($_GET['competition'])) ? $_GET['competition'] : '';
```

Generate the select from your competitions list. The list is only for demo :)

```
<select name="competition">
<?php foreach($competitions as $key => $value):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php echo ($selectedCompetition == $value) ? 'selected' : '';?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```